Using an enum to allow for a class instance to be using as a Generic Value
I noticed mypy will not raise an error when you provide a class instance for a generic type if you set the instance to an enum value first.  At times it would be useful to provide a literal class instance to identify the type of an object.
class MyKlass():
    pass

my_val = MyKlass()

class MyEnum(Enum):
     val = my_val

Literal[MyEnum.val]  # mypy doesnt complain 
Literal[x]  # mypy complains "Variable not allowed in type expression"

So if I have a Generic that I want to be able to provide an arbitrary value, I can do something like:
class MyEnum(Enum):
    val = my_val

class MyClass(Generic[T]):
    pass

# here I use the enum value.
MyClass[MyEnum.val]  # no issues

Is there a better way to do this?  I want to avoid providing the value as a function arg because it's much more relevant to the static type checker.

A variable by definition isn’t static. An Enum value is. This seems likely to be an XY problem. If you are using a variable to do something that is relevant to a static type checker, there is probably a better way to do it. Tell us what you are trying to accomplish instead of how you went about accomplishing it.

I realize it's somewhat unidiomatic, but I'd like for the generic type to be used to affect the behavior of the class.  Imagine I have configurations for a server, and I want to have MyClassPROD operate differently than MyClassSTAGING.  I like the syntax of using the class_getitem.

Enums are quite different from other classes, with class statements being heavily "abused" to define them. Type checkers are special cased to allow things like MyEnum.val to be recognized as literals, rather than arbitrary attribute-lookup expressions.

Depending on what you are doing, you many want to use typing.Annotated.

Why is it so important to do MyClass[PROD]() instead of MyClass(PROD)?  You said you want to avoid providing the value as a function arg because it's only relevant to the type checker, but then you said you want the runtime behavior of the class to be affected by the generic type -- which is it?
